# Mathematics / Signal theory behind billiard ball 'wave pendulum' effect

Tags: fourier, decomposition, wave

This [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1M8ciWSgc_k&feature=related) shows a very interesting effect.

What is the underlying science?

I have recently started studying Fourier theory and DSP, and and trying to understand what is going on in terms of the material I've been learning.  I would like to understand this from as many angles as possible.

For example, at 0:39 the signal forms two lines moving against one another,  and shortly before that I can clearly see two sine waves in the signal.

This reminds me of the illustrations at http://www.dspguide.com/ch3/2.htm

PS  not quite sure how to tag this

Comment: see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics). note that each  pendulum have different "rod" size and thus different oscillation

Comment: Can someone edit the link in the above comment?   The closing ) should be part of the link

Answer (score 9):

As was pointed out in a comment above, this is a simple consequence of the [dynamics of a pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_%28mathematics%29). There's nothing particularly signal-processing-related about this problem, just some simple physics and trigonometry.

For a pendulum that is displaced from its angular equilibrium point by an angle of $\theta_0$ with an angular velocity of $\omega_0 = 0$ at $t = 0$, for small initial angles, the motion of the pendulum can be approximated by [simple harmonic motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion):

$$
\theta(t) = \theta_0 \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}t\right)
$$

where $g$ is the magnitude of the force of gravity and $l$ is the length of the pendulum. In the video, a number of pendulums of varying lengths are given an approximately equal initial displacement $\theta_0$ and released simultaneously. Once they are released, each pendulum traces out a path whose displacement angle is a sinusoid with frequency related to the pendulum's length. The lengths were carefully chosen to give the interesting visual effect that you see in the video; the frequencies of the sinusoids are multiples of some fundamental frequency, so for particular values of $t$, they line up in interesting ways.

You'll notice toward the end, all of the balls "line up" again; this is because each of the sinusoids that describe their motion have moved through an integer number of periods, so the balls are back at a common angular displacement. If there were no effects of friction, air resistance, etc., the oscillation would continue, with the same patterns repeating indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I kind of realised that each ball is like a sinusoidal oscillator of k*f_0,  where k might run from 50 to 75 or something, which is sounding a lot like Fourier decomposition...

Comment: Of course it's signal processing related.  It's a discrete-time sine wave frequency sweep which bounces off the Nyquist frequency and aliases back to DC.  :)

Comment: @endolith: I agree. It's just the physics that aren't really DSP-related. It's a really neat demo that can be used to teach a lot of signal processing concepts, though. Makes me want to try to build one with my kids.

Comment: @endolith, RIGHT!  Now we are getting somewhere!  Would you be up for elaborating on that in a separate answer?   Forget the physics, I'm interested in how this can teach signal processing concepts -- how much DSP can be learned through this demonstration?